# Can't AddLiquidity to Uniswap with Ethers, Error cannot estimate gas but when added new error that I can't specific both gasPrice and maxFees

Tags: ethers.js, uniswap

I deployed a fork of uniswap v2 to sepolia and am trying to build a basic dex using ethers. I created the pair (is returned in getPair) and approved the Router contract with plenty of my token and weth to move.

```
  tx = await this.router.addLiquidityETH(
    tokenAddress,
    ethers.utils.parseEther('99'),
    ethers.utils.parseEther('98'),
    ethers.utils.parseEther('0.00019'),
    this.address,
    Math.trunc(Date.now() / 1000 + 3600),
    {
      value: ethers.utils.parseEther('0.0002'),
    }
  );
```

This tx immediately fails before it even pops up for a Metamask transaction approval or anything with the message

> Error: cannot estimate gas; transaction may fail or may require manual gas limit

Per that error message I try add gasLimit param `gasLimit: 310000` and the Metamask transaction happens as expected, but now fails with

> Error: both gasPrice and (maxFeePerGas or maxPriorityFeePerGas) specified at getResult

I've tried playing all manner with the values, approvals, gas params, etc... all to no avail, it always falls back to one of these errors.

**any ideas what I'm doing wrong? thanks**

Bonus; I'm guessing this is throwing some uniswap error message but I'm just not able to access it?